# SQL Server: Create index on view

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I created view on table and I'd like to create index on this view. When I created index only on view my query doesn't use index but when I create index on table and next the same index on view, query use index.

My view is creating new column based on other column with the same table which is based my view so I can't create index on table because i can't modify this table. It is possible created non clustered index on view which can improve my query? When I created non clustered index my query only table scan instead of use non clustered index.

Comment: Was your view properly created with the `WITH SCHEMABINDING` option?

Comment: You can certainly make indexed views, although they have some limitations.  Without lots more information, there is no way for us to say if indexing would help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you created first clustered and then regular index on the view with schemabinding, you can use WITH (NOEXPAND) when selecting from the view, then it "might" use your new index, ie:

```sql
select *
from dbo.vwIndexedView WITH (NOEXPAND)
WHERE indexedColumn = 1
```

Answer (score -1):

If your query mentions the base tables, the optimizer can use the index on the view only in Enterprise Edition. If your query mentions the index, you can force the index in the query :

```
SELECT *
FROM MyView WITH (INDEX = MyIndex)
```

But beware : it could lead to worse performances if the optimizer was right in the first place.

Comment: That's not true.  You can use NOEXPAND in Standard Edition to utilize an indexed view.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx